# Entity id availability in Custom Field

Tags: 8, path-aliases

I've created a Custom Field (let's call it 'Reference') whose value requires the Entity Id.

To accomplish that I modify the Field value in the postSave method, like this:

```
if (!$update) {
  $this->get('value')
    ->setValue($this->getCalculatedReferenciaValue());
}

public function getCalculatedReferenciaValue() {
  //...
  $entity = $this->getEntity();
  $id = $entity->id();
  $year = date("Y", $date);
  // default format: 'SWAN%s%08dIMOV'
  $format = $this->getSetting('format');
  return sprintf($format, $year, $id);
}
```

Then, in pathauto, I use that custom created field, as a token, to generate the path.

However, for some reason, when creating a node, my custom field still has the default value.

If I then edit and save the node, the custom field (and the auto path) is updated correctly.

**Q: Is there a way to update the field value so that it becomes available when generating the autopath for the first time?**

Answer (score 0):

For getting the node ID you need to first save the node. For eg:

```
$node = Node::create([
      'type' => 'my_content_type',
      'title' => 'My Title',
      'uid' => \Drupal::currentUser()->id(),
      'status' => 1
]);
$node->save();
    :
    :

$id = $node->id();
$year = date("Y", $date);
// default format: 'SWAN%s%08dIMOV'
$format = $this->getSetting('format');
$node->field_custom->value = sprintf($format, $year, $id);
$node->save();
```